Headless Development with React - Error HTTP 302 during JSS deploy app command
My goal is to do the Walkthrough on the official Sitecore Website
I did all the steps

execute jss setup, jss deploy config
add the binding in IIS and in my host file the domain.
API key has been created and used in my scjssconfig.json
verify that I have a valid license for Sitecore.JSS installed

I can't execute successfully the command
jss deploy app -c -d

That's the error message I get:
Sending package sitecore\package\jss-react.1723052147864.manifest.zip to http://jss-react.dev.local/sitecore/api/jss/import..
Unexpected response from import service:
Status message: Found
Status: 302

In my Sitecore log, I have this information :
WARN  Request is redirected to document not found page. Requested url: /sitecore/api/jss/import, User: extranet\Anonymous, Website: jss-react

I'm new with Sitecore, I needs your help to know how I can troubleshoot this error ?
Thanks

You will need to install Sitecore Headless package on Sitecore instance in order to solve this issue. This can be downloaded from below location depending on Sitecore version.
https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_Headless_Rendering
Note: You will need to install Sitecore Headless package when you are using Sitecore version 10 or later. In case version of Sitecore is less than 10, you need to download and install JSS package from below location on Sitecore instance.
https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services
Once above package is installed on Sitecore instance, you can re-run the above command again, this should solve the issue you are facing.
You can find more details for the installation here.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/latest/sitecore-headless-development/install-headless-services-using-the-package--zip-file.html
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
